# connecting an intermatic timer switch and a dimmer switch on the same lights

Tags: lighting, electrical-panel, switch, dimmer-switch, timer

I currently have an Intermatic timer switch on my lights, and I would like to add a dimmer switch next to the timer switch, because the lights are sometimes too bright, is it possible to have both a dimmer switch and a timer switch on one light?

The dimmer switch: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0771BC2YH?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0771BC2YH)

The Intermatic timer: [1]: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003A3V03A/ref=ox_sc_saved_image_1?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003A3V03A)

also will the dimmer switch interfere with the timer

Comment: Should be possible.  Think you need the timer first in circuit then the dimmer.  Dimmer might make the timer wonky if the dimmer is first.

Answer (score 1):

Tough question.  The issue is the problem of "dimming the timer".

If it is a hand-crank mechanical timer, like the classic Intermatics, then it doesn't matter since the timer is a "dumb" on/off switch powered by you.  I would put the dimmer first, and dim the timer, because I can comfortably say virtually every dimmer is OK with that, and will remember its brightness between uses.

However, if the timer has any internal electronics, or takes a neutral wire, then it needs to be first.  You can't dim a device with onboard electronics.

Comment: Hey Harp. I'm surprised you said to put the dimmer first. Whether electronic, mechanical motor driven, or hand crank, I would think they'd expect line voltage.  I see no point in putting the timer behind the dimmer.   I certainly agree with you regarding electronic timers.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson -- a wind-up timer only cares about the electricity supply insofar that its contacts are able to safely switch the voltage given to it

Comment: @George I have a wind-up timer on a 240V line.  They are just a dumb switch and don't care.  There is a minor cost to putting the dimmer downline of the timer: it will tend to lose its internal settings if it has any.